# Put external css file content into html header via typoscript for a newsletter

Tags: typo3, typoscript, newsletter

For a newsletter I need to put the content of an external css file into the page header.
I don't want to hardcode it in the fluidtemplate but use typoscript for that purpose.

Is it possible to put the file content into a `<style></style>` tag rather than a `<link rel .... />` file reference via typoscript?

thank you,but since the headerdata is of type CARRAY it had to be a number. 
`page.headerData.10 = FILE`

`page.headerData.10.file = path/../../file.css`

`page.headerData.10.wrap = <style>|</style>`

Answer (score 0):

With the `PAGE`Content Object it should be possible:

```
page.headerData.styles = FILE
page.headerData.styles.file = path/to/file.css
page.headerData.styles.wrap = <style>|</style>
```